# CrystalReports For Visual Studio 2017 Previous Versions on NuGet

Tags: crystal-reports, nuget

I moved development over to a new workstation and Visual Studio 2017.  I installed all the Crystal Decisions References using NuGet Package Manager for Solution from within VS2017 tools and installed the Runtime for 13.0.3501  Everything looked okay, until I tested the app on my client's PC where he also has SAGE 100 running a previous version of Crystal Reports.

SO, I need to back out Crystal Reports Engine for VS2017 to a previous version, I believe it will be 13.0.2000.0.

On NuGet I can only see V13.0.3500.

(I also see CrystalDecision 1.0.0 which is confusing...what's CrystalReports vs CrytalDecisions?)

How,where can I get a previous version?  I looked on the SAP website but didn't see how to get previous versions...if indeed this is the right approach to fixing the incompatibility issues.

Comment: Making some progress getting previous version:  From Crystal Reports, Developer for Visual Studio Downloads website you can copy Download link and paste into browser. Then Change version number to 13.0.20 which downloaded CR for VS 2010.  So, next, can I install CR for VS2010 on VS2017???

Comment: But, this will change my development platform for ALL my other projects as well.  Is there a way to use the CR dlls JUST in this one VS2017 application?